# Perl equivalent of PHP mysqli_data_seek

Tags: php, mysql, perl, dbi

PHP `mysqli_data_seek` adjusts the result pointer to an arbitrary row in the result.

Using `DBI` and `DBD::mysql` is there a Perl equivalent to the `PHP mysqli_data_seek` function?

Comment: Why not just use `LIMIT`?

Comment: That would require a new query each time.  I want to run the query only once.  I use the `mysqli_data_seek` function in PHP scripts and find it valuable.  I now have a requirement for an equivalent function in Perl.  I could rerun the query, but that seems like a waste.

Comment: Yes, but each query would be fetching a lot less data. Is this for paging or something like that?

Comment: That depends on many factors.  How many times will the query be executed, what is the range of the limit, how much data is returned, etc.  Obviously the PHP folks thought there was a good reason to develop such a function.  Why not Perl?

Comment: I don't use PHP, but from my reading of the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php), `mysqli_data_seek` is only possible with [buffered queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php), which read all results into memory. You can emulate this with `DBI` using one of the `fetchall_` or `selectall_` methods and using an array index or hash key to get the row you're interested in. Reading everything into memory won't work for really large result sets (with either PHP or Perl), so if your query returns lots of data, you should use `LIMIT`.

Comment: In my search I notice that in DBD::mysql version 3.0008 (http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-3.0008/lib/Mysql.pm) there was such a function called dataseek().  However, it seems that in all future versions of DBD::mysql the dataseek function is no longer present.  I looked at the ChangeLog file, but can find no mention of it.  Can anyone offer an explanation?

Comment: That documentation is for a completely different, obsolete module `Mysql.pm` (and its buddy `Msql.pm`). It was included in the `DBD::mysql` *distribution* until v4.x. As far as I can tell, `DBD::mysql` never documented a `dataseek` function, although ikegami found it in the XS source. And just to reiterate, you would get the exact same functionality by storing all results of your query in an array and indexing into it.

Comment: Yes, I agree with what you say about storing the results of the query in an array and I have taken that approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> $query->dataseek($row_number);

Comment: Note that it's [undocumented](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::mysql) (but a look at the [source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.028/mysql.xs) reveals it).

Comment: Is `$query` supposed to be a statement handle? I get `Can't locate object method "dataseek" via package "DBI::st"`

Comment: you need package linked by ikegami above

Comment: If you're referring to `DBD::mysql`, I do have it. Again, is `$query` supposed to be a statement handle?

Comment: dataseek() was in DBD::mysql version 3.0008, but not in any versions since then.  ChangeLog offers no explanation why.

Comment: @BrianG See comment on your question. What you found is a completely separate, obsolete module.

Comment: I communicated directly with the developer of DBD::mysql, Patrick Galbraith and he provided this answer that I think is helpful.  "dataseek() was an old pre-DBI function that I deprecated so the driver would conform to contemporary DBI drivers. I reckon having some sort of wrapper library do this might be worth doing this though you are the first person to notice it missing."